# Raising event in its class, calling it in another and attaching it in 3rd

Tags: c#, events, handlers

Hello i searched for a while but couldn't find a solution to my problem. And I am 100% sure that the solution is just a simple line of code which I can't figure out ;(
... So what I have here is a class with a delegate AlarmHandler and event AlarmEvent8 The event gets raised in the method IncreaseHoursBy1

```
class Clock
{
    public delegate void AlarmHandler(string info);

    public event AlarmHandler AlarmEvent8;


    private int minutes;
    private int hours;

    public int Minutes
    {
        get { return minutes; }
    }
    public int Hours
    {
        get { return hours; }
    }

    public Clock(int minutes, int hours)
    {
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public void IncreaseHoursBy1()
    {
        this.hours += 1;
        if(this.hours == 8)
        {
            if(AlarmEvent8 != null)
            {
                this.AlarmEvent8("Time to wake up!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to make a handler for the event in another class:

```
 class Person
{
    private string name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string EventHandler(string info)
    {
        return this.name + " " + info;

    }


}
```

And then finally I want to attach the Handler to the Event in my Form1's constructor but I have no idea how my Form1 constructor

```
    Clock myClock;
    Person Me;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myClock = new Clock(50, 2);
        Me = new Person("RandomPerson");

        myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(Me.EventHandler(info));
    }
```

What I currently have is giving me an error that "info" does not exist yet.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: As the message said, "info does not exist yet". In your `Form1()` method, there is no variable named `info`, so you can't use it in the last line.

Comment: How would I go about fixing it :?

Comment: I did it in a very "ugly" manner using the help from bellow I just changed the method to void type and added "using System.Windows.Forms;" to the Person class and then just put this:...
public void EventHandler(string info)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this.name + " " + info);
            
        }

Comment: @NikolaGrigorov - You're right that that is an ugly way to go. Part of the point of using events is to provide a separation of concerns. Your `Person` class should not need to know about the UI. In theory you should be able to use it interchangeably with WinForms, WPF, Console Apps, ASP.NET, etc, without changing the code. You really should change `public string EventHandler(string info)` to `public string AppendInfoToName(string info)` and just call it directly within an event handler outside of `Person`.

Comment: Yeah I didn't thought of that! I will keep that in mind for the next time.But for now I think the way I did it would be enough for the assignment I was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally wire up your handler like this:

```
myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(Me.EventHandler);
```

Note that the `info` variable is something that gets passed when the handler gets called and not when you're adding the handler.

However, in this case you get this syntax error:

> CS0407 'string Person.EventHandler(string)' has the wrong return type

You've got a little bit of weirdness going on here. Your `delegate` is defined as:

```
public delegate void AlarmHandler(string info);
```

Yet, the handler you're trying to attach to has this signature:

```
public string EventHandler(string info)
```

Note that the former's return type is `void` and the latter's is `string`. They're not compatible.

So you either have to change the signature of the `delegate` or the handler method to make them match.

The normal way to do it would be to have both return `void`. In that case the handler method in `Person` would have to be written something like this:

```
public void EventHandler(string info)
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.name + " " + info);
}
```

You can no longer return a value so you'd have to deal with the event then and there in some manner. I've chosen to write the value to the console.

However, if you change the delegate to return `string` then you would be able to handle the return value in the event raising code, like so:

```
public void IncreaseHoursBy1()
{
    this.hours += 1;
    if (this.hours == 8)
    {
        if (AlarmEvent8 != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.AlarmEvent8("Time to wake up!"));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I run either of these variants with this code:

```
var myClock = new Clock(50, 2);
var Me = new Person("RandomPerson");

myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(Me.EventHandler);

myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
```

I get the following output:

```
RandomPerson Time to wake up!
```

However, the difference comes with this code:

```
var myClock = new Clock(50, 2);
var Me1 = new Person("Person 1");
var Me2 = new Person("Person 2");

myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(Me1.EventHandler);
myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(Me2.EventHandler);

myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
```

If I run this with the `void`-returning `delegate` code I get this output:

```
Person 1 Time to wake up!
Person 2 Time to wake up!
```

And if I run it with the `string-returning`delegate` code I only get this:

```
Person 2 Time to wake up!
```

If you attach more than one handler to an event that returns a value then only the last delegate's return value is passed back - even though both handlers ran.

You really should try to stick with `void`-returning delegates.

The other option, is, as presented by Vikhram, to use your original code and do this:

```
myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(info => Me.EventHandler(info));
```

However, this throws away the return value from the `Me.EventHandler(info)` call. It would be useful here to do something with the return value like this:

```
myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(info => Console.WriteLine(Me.EventHandler(info)));
```

So, if I now go to this code:

```
var myClock = new Clock(50, 2);
var Me1 = new Person("Person 1");
var Me2 = new Person("Person 2");

myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(info => Console.WriteLine(Me1.EventHandler(info)));
myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(info => Console.WriteLine(Me2.EventHandler(info)));

myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
myClock.IncreaseHoursBy1();
```

And run it, I get this output:

```
Person 1 Time to wake up!
Person 2 Time to wake up!
```

Which is, I think, what you probably want to do.

The three different approaches show that you can handle the result computed in the `public string EventHandler(string info)` in three different locations. It's really up to you to decide what works for you best.

Comment: Yeah i changed to void type and instead of using Console.Writeline I just used Messagebox.Show(); in the person class, i had to add to the person class to use system.windows.forms and in the end it worked. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @NikolaGrigorov - I appended a third option to my answer that may also appeal.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will stick to void types for now! :D

Comment: @NikolaGrigorov - Actually the third option I gave you is still using `void` types. It means that you can rename `EventHandler` to `AppendInfoToName`, because the handler then would be `info => Console.WriteLine(Me.AppendInfoToName(info))` and not `AppendInfoToName` directly.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need the info there. The line should look something like below

```
myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(info => Me.EventHandler(info));
```

Also, you can change the EventHandler itself to not return anything (which is usually how it is done)

```
public void EventHandler(string info)
myClock.AlarmEvent8 += new Clock.AlarmHandler(Me.EventHandler);
```

Comment: Did you try this code? - `CS0407 'string Person.EventHandler(string)' has the wrong return type`

Comment: It doesn't have to be a string method, it could be a void, but with void I don't know how to give the "this.name" to the Event

Comment: Please remove the downvote since the presented answer resolves the issue

Comment: Yeah it resolved my issue, but I am not the person who downvoted your comment. Thank you for the help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: If it resolved your issue, you should accept the answer